# How to print/select a column based on result of another column in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I want to write a select statement.

- If the value in the column: **SCHEDULE_STATUS** is "*SCHEDULED*" then only the column: **SCHEDULED_ON** need to be print in the result
- If the value in the column: **SCHEDULE_STATUS** is "*NOT_SCHEDULED*" then the column: **SCHEDULED_ON** not to be print in the result.

1.If Schedule_Status = NOT_SCHEDULED then Scheduled_On column is not supposed to appear in the result.

```
Actual Result:
+------+-----------------+--------------------+
| Name | Schedule_Status |    Scheduled_On    |
+------+-----------------+--------------------+
| ABC  | NOT_SCHEDULED   | 29-FEB-20 23:30:50 |
+------+-----------------+--------------------+
```

```
Expected Result:
+------+-----------------+
| Name | Schedule_Status |
+------+-----------------+
| ABC  | NOT_SCHEDULED   |
+------+-----------------+
```

2. If Schedule_Status = SCHEDULED then Scheduled_On column is supposed to appear in the result.

```
 Actual Result:
+------+-----------------+--------------------+
| Name | Schedule_Status |    Scheduled_On    |
+------+-----------------+--------------------+
| ABC  | SCHEDULED   | 29-FEB-20 23:30:50 |
+------+-----------------+--------------------+
```

```
Expected Result:
+------+-----------------+--------------------+
| Name | Schedule_Status |    Scheduled_On    |
+------+-----------------+--------------------+
| ABC  | SCHEDULED   | 29-FEB-20 23:30:50 |
+------+-----------------+--------------------+
```

In the second criteria, the actual result and the expected result is the same, My worry is only about the first criteria.

Please help me one the first criteria.

Comment: Show desired result when there exists 2 records - one with `Schedule_Status = 'SCHEDULED'` and another with `Schedule_Status = 'NOT_SCHEDULED'`.

Comment: I will get either Schedule_Status = 'SCHEDULED' or  Schedule_Status = 'NOT_SCHEDULED'.
I won't get both Schedule_Status = 'SCHEDULED' and  Schedule_Status = 'NOT_SCHEDULED'.

Comment: In general the SQL server output structure must be deterministic. I'd recommend simply replace the value for `Scheduled_On` with NULL or empty string when `Schedule_Status = 'NOT_SCHEDULED'` is queried, and ignore this empty field presence in the output on the client side.

Answer (score 2):

You can try with CASE statement to achieve your required output. Check this below logic-

```
SELECT 
CASE 
    WHEN SCHEDULE_STATUS = 'SCHEDULED' THEN SCHEDULED_ON
    ELSE NULL
END 
FROM your_table
```

As per your clarification, you can use a simple select statement with WHERE condition as below-

```
SELECT * 
FROM your_table
WHERE SCHEDULE_STATUS = 'SCHEDULED'
```

Comment: Hi mkRabbani

Thanks for the case statement logic
After trying your suggestion, I am getting the column with a NULL value if in the column: SCHEDULE_STATUS is "NOT_SCHEDULED".
Can't I fully avoid the column: SCHEDULED_ON?

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean by fully avoid? Blank in place of NULL? or you wants that full row to be disappear? or something else?

Comment: full row to be disappear

Comment: It's a where clause `Select * from table where SCHEDULE_STATUS = 'SCHEDULED' `

Comment: @DeepuAnudeep Please check the added new script.

Comment: Sorry I am correcting my question, Full Column: SCHEDULED_ON need to disappear if column: SCHEDULE_STATUS is "NOT_SCHEDULED".

Comment: please add some expected result on your question and if you can maybe add some fiddle so we can help your problems

Comment: Hi Fachry Dzaky Al-Qadri Sabil 

I had given the expected results in the question, Please check and help me on the first criteria.

Comment: You can not make a column disappear for a SPECIFIC ROW. Either it will be available for all row Or no row. That's why the first script is the best solution for you to fill the column with NULL or a Blank space.

Comment: Ok, Thank you @mkRabbani

Answer (score 0):

This is one of many ways to achieve what you desire:

1. `*` selects all columns data from the table, if you don't want to show that last column then just select the first two columns,
2. t1 is your current table,
3. Query the table to only retrieve data where the `Schedule_Status` is `NOT_SCHEDULED`.

   ```
   SELECT Name, Schedule_Status
   FROM t1 
   WHERE t1.Schedule_Status = "NOT_SCHEDULED";
   ```